# Backup to a synology NAS with bup

Tags: backup, environment-variables, python, troubleshooting, bup

I am trying to make a remote backup to my Synology NAS (DSM 4.1) using `bup`.

I compiled `bup` on my NAS from source, did there:

```
 BUP_DIR=/volume1/public/Backups/bup bup init
Initialized empty Git repository in /volume1/public/Backups/bup/
```

Then I tried: `bup save --remote=root@192.168.1.90:/volume1/public/Backups/bup -n bubtest /home/user/BackupTest` on my laptop but got the following error message:

```
env: python: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/bup/cmd/bup-save", line 74, in <module>
    cli = client.Client(opt.remote)
  File "/usr/lib/bup/bup/client.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.check_ok()
  File "/usr/lib/bup/bup/client.py", line 132, in check_ok
    return self.conn.check_ok()
  File "/usr/lib/bup/bup/helpers.py", line 389, in check_ok
    return self._check_ok(onempty)
  File "/usr/lib/bup/bup/helpers.py", line 377, in _check_ok
    raise Exception('server exited unexpectedly; see errors above')
bup.client.ClientError: server exited unexpectedly; see errors above
```

On my laptop `which python` tells me `/usr/bin/python`. On my NAS `which python` gives `/opt/bin/python`.

Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to fix this is to add a symlink. As root:

```
ln -s /opt/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

You can test it with this command:

```
env python
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fixes the problem. However now there is another error message that has nothing to do with the env problem... Perhaps I try to ask on the bup mailing list...

Answer (score 1):

Note: I know nothing specific about bup.

It sounds like /opt/bin is not in your PATH on your NAS.
As root (the user you use to login on your NAS using bup) try:

```
env | grep PATH
```

And see if it is there. If it's not, try adding it in root's shell (eg .bashrc).

edit: I just remembered that which probably already looks in the PATH. In that case, it may be that bup on your NAS edits or throws away the PATH. You could try making a script that starts bup with a correct PATH variable.

Sample script

```
!#/bin/sh
PATH="$PATH:/opt/bin" /path/to/bup
```

Comment: Thanks. `/opt/bin` is in `PATH`. How do I make the script you suggested?

Comment: It depends a bit on how bup works. I thought `/volume1/public/Backups/bup` was an executable but now that I read it again I think it's a directory? I've added a sample script in my post, just in case